# In Firestore security rules, can a custom function be used inside another custom function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore security rules, I'm writing a custom function (`isEitherNotSecretOrIsOwner()`), with another custom function (`belongsToRequestor()`) inside of it, but the [official Google Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) on custom functions seems to be silent on whether this is okay or not.

Code excerpt below:

```
function belongsToRequestor() {
return request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId
}

function isEitherNotSecretOrIsOwner() {
resource.data.reviewPrivacy != 'keepSecret' ||
belongsToRequestor()
}
```

*I hope this is okay, because I need to put the `isEitherNotSecretOrIsOwner()` inside a longer set of `&&` conditions and I'm not sure how else to have the "either X || Y" inside a string of  `&&` conditions…*

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems to me that, if it works, then it's OK.  The rules engine will not accept invalid rules. Why would you not think this is OK?

Comment: Thanks Doug. I hadn't looked at it that way. I'll went ahead and tried and got an "unexpected resource" error regarding ```resource.data.reviewPrivacy != 'keepFullySecret'```. I tried replacing that with "request.auth != null" and got another error, so I'm guessing the answer is no (though I'm not certain enough to submit this as an answer, in case I'm wrong).

Comment: Update: I don't think my ```resource.data.reviewPrivacy != 'keepSecret'``` would work anyway, because it seems to violate the "Rules are not filters" principle, described at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling one custom functions from within another one is indeed supported in Firestore security rules, as long as the function you're calling is in scope at the call site.

Comment: Update: I don't think my ```resource.data.reviewPrivacy != 'keepSecret'``` would work, because it seems to violate the "Rules are not filters" principle, described at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters

Comment: Your question was about scoping of functions, but I have a sense now it was a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you're having a problem to make something work, it is usually better to post the actual problem rather than derived conclusion on its cause. E.g. with your minimal rules and code, we could've very quickly pointed to rules not being filters and it sounds like that'd have been more helpful to you.